# WP-all-import problems with large input file

Tags: import, xml

I'm running development environment xampp (windows) and production server.

On the DEV virtual machine, everything works correctly, PROD server doesn't work:

- wp-all-import plugin
- large XML feed http://www.zoot.cz/exports/affiliate.xml (175 MB)
- login to wp wp-all-import -> new import -> from URL
- file correctly downloaded to server -> AJAX redirect to "xpath builder" -> xpath "/PRODUCT" AJAX returns only 15 results
- no NOTICE/WARNING/ERROR in php log
- DEV machine imports all 82600 records correctly

I tried to find php config differences, but memory limit, script exec time etc. are the same...

dev machine is PHP 5.4, production PHP 5.3 (but newer version of libxml than in dev)...

Any idea, what could possibly cause the problem?

Thanks

Comment: so how is this a wordpress specific problem? you are not even using the same PHP versions and who knows what are the other differences.

Comment: you are right... after long 2 days (because wp-all-import plugin uses `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`), I've found out, it is encoding issue (source xml file, claims it's utf8, but contains some invalid bytes sequences)... due to the libxml errors turned off, no record in php log was found... for some reason, windows was able to cope with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong source file encoding (not utf8 as xml prolog claims), wp-all-import wordpress plugin hid the php error